# How to use nested foreach loop in .cshtml file in MVC ASP .net C#

Tags: c#, asp.net-mvc, razor, foreach

I am creating an application in which I am retrieving data from two different table using Mysql database. And I get that data properly but the problem is that when I try to display it on a view using foreach loop then data is not display in proper manner.

Here is my code:

Controller

```
public ActionResult me()
{

      ViewAllData objviewalldata = new ViewAllData();
      // var emp1 = db.emps.FirstOrDefault(e => e.empid == 1);
      //  objviewalldata.deptname = emp1.dept.deptname;
      // objviewalldata.empname = emp1.empname;


      var emp1 = new ViewAllData();

      MySqlConnection con = new MySqlConnection(@"server=127.0.0.1;user id=root;pwd=n0711p2010p;database=demo;persistsecurityinfo=True");
      using (con)
      {
          con.Open();
          string query = "select emp.empname,dept.deptname from emp inner join dept on emp.deptid=dept.deptid";
          using (MySqlCommand cmd = new MySqlCommand(query, con))
          {
                MySqlDataReader dr;
                emp1.alllemp = new List<string>();
                emp1.alldept = new List<string>();
                using ( dr = cmd.ExecuteReader())
                {
                    while (dr.Read())
                    {
                        emp1.empname = dr["empname"].ToString();
                        emp1.deptname = dr["deptname"].ToString();

                        emp1.alllemp.Add(emp1.empname);
                        emp1.alldept.Add(emp1.deptname);
                    }
                }
           }
      }
      return View(emp1);


}
```

View.cshtml

```
@model  MvcApplication3.Models.ViewAllData

@{
    ViewBag.Title = "Data";
}

<h2>Data</h2>


<table>
    <tr>
        <th>Employee Name</th>
        <th>Depart Name</th>
    </tr>

@foreach (string item in Model.alllemp)
{ <tr>

        <td>@Html.Label(item)</td>

     @foreach (string item1 in Model.alldept)
        {
          <td>@Html.Label(item1)</td>
        } 

       </tr>  

}

</table>
```

this is my output

[image]

I want output like

```
Employee Name Department Name
Neel          Software
Nisarg        Software
Prachi        Embeded
```

Comment: What do you mean by `data is not display in proper manner`

Comment: "data is not display in proper manner" does not gives any useful information. You should post more details about your question, like "what is your actual expected output" and "how it currently behaves", etc.

Comment: It would be good if you can share the generated output rather then just saying "data is not displayed in proper manner".

Comment: I added my generated output and also describe there how i except output @Tayyab

Comment: You can use approach as in [this fiddle](https://dotnetfiddle.net/88PCAf). Using a class that holds 2 properties and iterate them can make desired output.

Comment: @TetsuyaYamamoto thanks buddy it's a useful , but i got my solution

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Just replace the foreach loop with a simple for loop as your output can be generated without the nesting:

```
<table>
<tr>
    <th>Employee Name</th>
    <th>Depart Name</th>
</tr>

@for (int i=0; i < Model.allemp.Count;i++)
{
<tr>

    <td>@Html.Label(Model.allemp[i])</td>

    <td>@Html.Label(Model.alldept[i])</td>


</tr>

}
```

Comment: Happy to help :)

Answer (score 0):

It makes mistake result in the codes as follows:

```
 emp1.alllemp.Add(emp1.empname);
 emp1.alldept.Add(emp1.deptname);
```

Maybe you can declare ViewAllData as follows:

```
public List<VO> emps {get;set;}

public class VO 
{
   public string empname {get;set;}
   public string deptname {get;set;}
}
```

Then, modify codes in data layer.

```
using ( dr = cmd.ExecuteReader())
{
   while (dr.Read())
   {
      VO vo = new VO();
      vo.empname = dr["empname"].ToString();
      vo.deptname = dr["deptname"].ToString();

      emp1.emps.Add(vo);
   }
}
```

Then, modify code in view layer.

```
@foreach (string item in Model.emps)
{ 
  <tr>
   <td>@Html.Label(item.empname)</td>
   <td>@Html.Label(item.deptname)</td>     
  </tr>  
}
```

Comment: Your answer is also useful,but i found a my solution just above your answer and just have to change my loop . and in your answer i have to change a lot. but thanks for the your kind answer :)